# iOS 8 - UIKeyboard hide auto-correct ribbon

Tags: ios, ios8, uikeyboard, autocorrect

I'm looking to programmatically minimize the auto-correct ribbon found in iOS 8. Minimize meaning achieving the same effect as tapping and sliding the auto-correct ribbon down to hide/minimize it. I know how to remove it completely with `_myTextView.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;` - but this does not give the option to pull it back up if the user still wants it.

I haven't been able to find much about it. When I search for ...

> hide autocorrect ribbon ios 8 sdk

Not much is returned of value. I've tried variations of that search but to no avail. Does anyone know if it's possible to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Currently i said no. Apple likes to give those kind of setting to the user only; not for developers. If you really need it off, you would have to design/create a [Custom Keyboard](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Keyboard.html).